# How would I got about using a `\foreach` loop to draw a grid of circles with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I have the following code

```latex
\draw (3, 3) circle (0.25) node[anchor=south, above=0.2cm]{$\vec{B}$};
\filldraw (3, 3) circle (0.05);
\draw (-3, 3) circle (0.25) node[anchor=south, above=0.2cm]{$\vec{B}$};
\filldraw (-3, 3) circle (0.05);
\draw (-3, -3) circle (0.25) node[anchor=south, above=0.2cm]{$\vec{B}$};
\filldraw (-3, -3) circle (0.05);
\draw (3, -3) circle (0.25) node[anchor=south, above=0.2cm]{$\vec{B}$};
\filldraw (3, -3) circle (0.05);
```

It gets pretty repetitive writing this, it would be nice to have it handled by a for loop in one shot; however, I don't understand how loops (and variables?) work in LaTeX to get this to work properly.

EDIT:
From @user237299's answer, I came up with the following, although I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way to go about it:

```latex
\foreach \x in {-3, 3}{
    \foreach \y in {-3, 3}{
        \draw (\x, \y) circle (0.25) node[anchor=south, above=0.2cm]{$\vec{B}$};
        \filldraw (\x, \y) circle (0.05);
    }
};
```

Comment: Would you accept user237299's answer? It's already doing what you asked :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest `foreach` loops.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path foreach \x in {-3,3} {foreach \y in {-3,3}
 {(\x,\y) node[circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm,
    label={above:{$\vec{B}$}}]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```